# Coldfusion zip folder doesn't open on Windows

Tags: coldfusion

I have a script that creates a zip file for download, it works great and unzips just fine if you have WinRar but if the user is using windows to unzip things it throws up an error.

"Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'C:\Downloads\Users.zip' is invalid"

It works great if using WinRar, any ideas how to make this work with windows unzipping component?

What header I'm using, maybe this is what could be causing it?

```
<cfcontent type="application/zip" reset="false" />
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=#archiveFilename#">
```

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the mime type

Comment: Yeah it's very strange. I don't think I have anything set for mime in the code you think that could be it?

Comment: No, the MIME type won't be relevant here. It does not actually affect the contents of the file. Can you drop the file somewhere for us to test with? Better, create a decent repro case (files to zip, code to zip 'em) so we can run locally & test. Which version of ColdFusion (including patch level), btw?

Comment: Silly question, but where is the code that actually serves up the file for downloading? That `cfcontent` tag is not doing anything without a "variable" or "file" attribute.

Comment: Also, did you try opening the file directly on the server first? ie That would either eliminate or confirm the download code as the source of the problem.

Comment: @Leigh does it not still set the MIME type HTTP header? Even if it's not itself providing the data for the response?

Comment: (Edit) @AdamCameron - Sure, but without any data ie variable/file the code is kind of useless ;-) So either there is a fundamental problem here, or he did not post a key part of his "download" script. (Granted, I was typing as you were posting, so my hint to "post the actual/full code..." is a bit redundant now).